# How to crop image without loosing any portion of uploaded image using php?

Tags: php

Well, In my site I am trying to crop image with following php function :

```
function image_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
           $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
           $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
    $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($tci, 255, 255, 255);    
    imagefill($tci, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
        imagegif($tci, $newcopy);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
        imagepng($tci, $newcopy);
    } else { 
        imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 84);
    }
}
```

But it's not working what I exactly want.

For example : I have a image which size is : `720 x 478`. When I resize it with this function (I can set the width and height in function call) it's cropping the image based on width. For e.g. I am calling it like that:

```
image_resize($file_destination, "../users_avator/ppic_$file_new_name", 200, 200, $file_ext);
```

It's saved the image with 200 x 132 size. **but which I don't want**

I want to crop the image exactly 200 x 200 size but **without cutting any portion of the image**. Like :

I see a website called cozymeal.com When I upload the same image in the profile section which size is `720 x 478` it's magically crop the image size to 200 x 200 **without cutting any portion of the image**.

**Original Image :**

[image]

**My cropping result :**

[image]

**Cozymeal cropping result :**

[image]

My question is How can I fix my function / crop any images like this cozymeal.com cropping system ? I mean custom size without loosing any image portion.

Comment: I would recommend utilizing imagick if it's available to you. I can post an example code for that should you want it.

Comment: using this custom function.

Comment: is there any solution @jjonesdesign ?

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I'm actually working at Cozymeal. We get this feature with our CDN cloudinary but you can use this library if you want to crop images as you want: https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

All the doc is inside the plugin

If you don't feel comfortable with this library you can use one of the following: https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php#imagery

Good luck :)